# Prototype and Closure

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am trying to solve some JavaScript questions about prototype (and maybe closure). I am **very** new to this concept.

I need to create a MyNumber prototype, then add increment function which will return a number that is incremented by 1. Here I will create multiple instances of the prototype and every instance will keep track of its own value separately.

Here is my logically broken code:

```
function MyNumber(num) {
  this.num = num;
}

MyNumber.prototype.increment = function() {
   return function() {
     ++this.num
   }
}
```

After this example, I need to create a Clock prototype, which will increment by one every second.

Comment: `setTimeout`? Btw, given that ES2015 is 4.5 years old now, what is the reason for you to not use JS classes?

Comment: I don't know, just trying to do solve these questions. Can you give me code examples, please?

Comment: It's hard to help you given you did not explain your problem or even asked a question.

Comment: I think you have some confusion with how your `increment` method is written-- you are needlessly returning a function with the implementation rather than simply executing the implementation when `increment` is called.  I'm not sure if this is a typo or the result of some confusion, but if you remove that it works fine.  For it to work the way that you have it written, above, it would need to be called as `instance.increment()()`, but obviously unless you have a compelling reason to do so there's not much value in that sort of superfluous "currying".

Comment: @AlexanderNied "For it to work the way that you have it written" --- it won't even work like that, because after the first invocation the context is lost, so `this` would refer to a global object, or undefined. It would be more like `instance.increment().call(instance)`

Comment: @zerkms - you are totally correct-- my mistake.  For it to work, in that manner, it would have to return an arrow function expression, so as written it simply won't work.  Thanks for calling that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you're using function constructors, I would suggest you use ES6's [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes). It will allow you to write more readable and maintainable code. Your `MyNumber` function can be made into a `class` by creating your own `constructor()` and `increment()` methods. The `increment()` method is in charge of incrementing the number and returning the new number.

Since you need a clock, you could also make an additional `Clock` class. This `extends` the `MyNumber` class, which allows `Clock` to access the properties and methods declared in the `MyNumber` class. Since a clock needs to have an internal counter we can extend `MyNumber` which provides this counting functionality for us.

The `Clock` class has a constructor which calls the `MyNumber`'s constructor by doing a `super()` call. This initializes what `this.num` will be in our `Clock` class. The constructor also accepts additional arguments such as an action, which is a function that gets executed every time the clock "ticks" and a `speed` for how fast the clock should "tick".

The `Clock` class also implements a `begin()` method, which uses `setInterval()` to repeatedly execute the passed through arrow function. The arrow function is executed every *x* m/s (based on the `this.speed` property). Every time the arrow function is executed, it increments the clocks internal counter (using the `.increment()` provided by the extended `MyNumber` class). It also executes the `action` function passed through the constructor initially.

You can then create an instance of your `Clock` class and pass through the required arguments to the constructor like so:

```js
class MyNumber {
  constructor(num) {
    this.num = num;
  }
  
  increment() {
    return ++this.num;
  }
}

class Clock extends MyNumber {
  constructor(beginTime, action, speed=1) { // default speed to `1`
    super(beginTime);
    this.act = action;
    this.speed = speed; // in seconds
  }
  
  begin() {
    this.act(this.num); // call once before looping
    setInterval(() => { // executes every `this.speed` seconds
      const new_time = this.increment(); // increment the time and get the new time
      this.act(new_time); // execute the action
    }, this.speed*1000); 
  }
}

const clock = new Clock(3, t => console.log(`Tick tock, the time is ${t}`));
clock.begin();
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem I see here is that rather than your `increment` method simply incrementing `this.num`, it returns a *`function`* that increments `this.num`.  In the example below, I rewrote it to simply do the incrementing itself.  Also in the example we make sure we create new instances using the [`new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new), so that the JS engine knows we're creating a new instance of an object:

```js
function MyNumber(num) {
  this.num = num;
}

MyNumber.prototype.increment = function() {
  ++this.num;
}

let myNumA = new MyNumber(10);
let myNumB = new MyNumber(100);

console.log(myNumA.num); // 10
console.log(myNumB.num); // 100

myNumB.increment();

console.log(myNumA.num); // 10
console.log(myNumB.num); // 101
```